# Unable to request offline access for Google Plus API

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, google-plus, google-oauth

I have a problem with Oauth2 Authorization.
I'm using `google-api-php-client` to communicate with G+ server. Init URL seems OK (generated by lib with `setAccessType('offline')`). But each time user connects Google don't ask about offline access. And of course a little bit later token becomes expired.

Here is the example of generated URL

`https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?response_type=code&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fwebaserver.com%2Fapp_dev.php%2Fsocial%2Fgoogle%2Fcallback&client_id=271195014651.apps.googleusercontent.com&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fplus.login+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.email&access_type=offline&approval_prompt=force&state=319d6021eeec33122901e36e7ce9149d`

Am i forgot some important details?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you accepted the ToS for G+ API? If not, that's probably why your application is being barred. Visit the project console and look for the APIs tab.

More detail on parameters:

- If you include 'approval_prompt=force' you will prompt the users to re-authorize *every* time. You should remove it unless you're doing for a very specific reason (lost refresh_tokens on database corruption event, for instance).
- If you include access_type=offline you'll obtain a refresh_token whenever the user sees a consent page. You should store it and re-use it after the initial access_token has expired.

Answer (score 1):

Was `access_type=offline` in place the first time the user authorized the app? I'm guessing not.

The system will only send a refresh token the **first** time you request authorization, even if you use `approval_prompt=force` or you change the access_type to offline at some later point.

You can to go the [Manage Apps](https://plus.google.com/u/0/apps) page and `Edit App` by hovering over the app and then clicking on the pencil that appears. You can then select `Disconnect` and the auth system will treat future logins as if it was the first time you're authenticating to the app again. You should use this system instead of `approval_prompt=force` to test against the first-time user experience.

Comment: Yes, that was my first suggestion, but app access is revoked each time before  I test it.